# Minikube's kubectl path. Where is kubectl?

Tags: path, kubectl, minikube

Kubectl is included with minicube. I use it. I need path to minikube's kubectl to use VS Code's Kubernetes extension. I don't want to install kubectl separetely

Chat GPT suggested me:

`echo "$(minikube kubectl -- get pods | grep -o '/.*kubectl')"`

But there is no output.

It also pointed me to

`<Minikube Installation Directory>/k8s/bin/kubectl`

But there is no bin directory in k8s directory.

Manual search returned:

`/proc/2103/task/2103/cwd/cache/linux/amd64/v1.27.4/kubectl`

`/proc/2103/cwd/cache/linux/amd64/v1.27.4/kubectl`

But those paths are weird and I don't know if safe to use.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with minikube but `kubectl` appears to be [`minikube kubectl`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/). So, I think it's not installed as a separate binary but, as part of the `minikube` binary. You should be able to `which minikube` to find your `minikube` binary. You will want to use that value but you'll need to provide `kubectl --` as arguments to it.

Comment: Will vs code's Kuberenetes extension accept it? Doesn't it require path?
`/usr/bin/minikube kubectl --` isn't just path, right?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with minikube, it appears that the `minikube` binary includes a command `kubectl`. In which case, you'll need the path (`/usr/bin`), the command (`minikube`) and the arguments (`kubectl --`). If, there's a standalone `kubectl` binary, then you can just use that.

Comment: `kubectl` and `minikube kubectl` are separate executables. The former is what you get when you install `kubectl` individually, the latter comes with `minikube`. In your case, using `alias` or symbolic link might work just fine for the extension.